# (pythonanywhere)Как подключиться к БД MySQL через Python скрипт?

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

Здраствуйте, у меня есть такой скрипт подключения:

```py
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='IvanShnirssPiton',
    passwd='мой пароль',
    host='IvanShnirssPiton.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    port='3306',
    database='IvanShnirssPiton$ProjectOneDB'
)
```

Но при попытке соединения вылетает такая ошибка:

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IvanShnirssPiton.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (10060)

Comment: Попробуйте указать `database='ProjectOneDB'`.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов не помогло, но спасибо всеровно.

Comment: Что ж. Попробовал сам. DNS-имя хоста резолвится, но пакеты до конечного хоста не доходят ни с домашней машины, ни с машины в гугл облаке. Сложилось ощущение, что СУБД на pythonanywhere доступна только из приложений на самом pythonanywhere. Возможно, об этом даже написано где-то у них в документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Accessing your MySQL database from outside PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/)

---

### Вольный перевод:

СУБД MySQL на PythonAnywhere защищены фаерволом, таким образом, внешние компьютеры не смогут получить доступ к ним.

Тем не менее, если у Вас есть платный аккаунт, Вы можете получить доступ к MySQL, используя SSH туннель, который, по факту, создаёт защищённое соединение с нашими системами, после чего общаться с MySQL поверх SSH туннеля.

Comment: Спасибо!Очень помоглы